# Having trouble with remainder division and not allowing dividing by zero (c++)

Tags: c++

Hi I am relatively new with c++ and to stack overflow. If there are any specific protocols when it comes to asking a question please be brutally honest so that I don't make the same mistake when I ask other questions.

I am trying to create a program that takes the inputs shown in the picture below. I want to make it so that the user can't divide by zero. I also want to have decimal outputs after the calculations but the program rounds to down. For example, if I put that a stock share price is 50 1/2 and have 10 of them then it shows 500 instead of 505.

Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define addr(var) & var // programmer defined macro definition 
#define MAXINT 2^32-1
int main(void)
{
char Ticker[6+1]; //Declare Ticker as String
int numOfShares;
float whole,num,dem;
float pricePerShare;
float stockValue; 
int i=0;
bool inputOK = false;
int value;
    
    
    
for (i=1; i <= 10; i++)
{
        
printf("Enter the stock Ticker ==> ");
scanf("%s",&Ticker[0]);         //Accept Ticker
printf("How many shares of %s were purchased: ",Ticker);
scanf("%d",&numOfShares);
printf("What is the price per share: ");
scanf("%d %d/%d",addr(whole), addr(num), addr(dem));
            
pricePerShare = whole + num / dem;
stockValue = numOfShares * pricePerShare;
            
printf("            Ticker  Number of   Price Stock\n");
printf("            Symbol  Share       Per Share  Value\n");
printf("            =====   ==========  =========  ======\n");
printf("%6s     %4d         %7.2f       %8.2f\n",
Ticker, numOfShares,pricePerShare,stockValue);
// %7.2f --> 9999.99
}

printf(" Press any key to continue ...");
            
fflush(stdin);
getchar();
return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures with code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I see you're a new contributor, so I advise you to check out [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also [please don't post code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Images cannot be copied into answers and are not viewable to some users, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: If someone wants to test your code locally, they have to type in everything, all due to images being posted.

Comment: I have deleted the picture and uploaded the code. If there are additional discrepancies please let me know. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: `%d` specifier expects a pointer to `int` as an argument. You pass a pointer to `float`. Whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior. With `scanf`, you have to be very careful about matching the format specifier and the type of the corresponding argument.

Answer (score 1):

When trying your code, I had a different problem from yours. Seems like it would always truncate the integer part instead of the decimal part.

Either way, I was able to fix it by changing

```
scanf("%d %d/%d", ....
```

to

```
scanf("%f %f/%f", ....
```

However, not sure if that would work for you.

**Edit:**

Just confirmed that seems to be the problem(or at least on my device).

When `whole` `num` and `dem` are declared as `float`, and you are scanning them in as `int` or `%d`, it actually convert the integer into some other number(not sure what those are tho), and that must have caused the problems.

Also another way to fix if you want to keep the `scanf("%d %d/%d ....`

You could declare those value as `int` at the beginning, and cast either `num` or `dem` into `float` when you do the calculation:

`pricePerShare = whole + float(num) / dem;`

Comment: Awesome, it seems to have worked. Now I just need to align the columns. One last question, how do I prevent division by zero and force re entry? Thanks a lot! @Ranoiaetep

Comment: @ddr98 You can definitely do a `if` statement after you have scanned the input. `if (dem == 0) { printf("re-enter"); scanf("%d %d/%d ....`

Comment: @ddr98 also consider using `std::cout` and `std::cin` if you are going along with c++. Different syntax and formatting, but will automatically cast your types correctly. It also give you easy ways of printing custom types.